# Thread 1: EXC_BAD ACCESS error when trying to change NSString to String or Access NSString

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring

I'm trying to get a file path from `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` in Swift. It's returning an `NSString`, but if I try and do ANYTHING to it (even print it) I get `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1 address=0x20)` error.

I've been banging my head against the wall for a while now as this is occurring in a couple of places and I've tried so many variations of code.

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)
    if (request.URL?.absoluteString!.rangeOfString("attachment=true") != nil) {

        // This line only succeeds with 'as! [NSString]'. If I try 'as! [String]' it fails.
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as! [NSString]

        // On this line I get the error if I leave the above array as [AnyObject]
        // And try and convert this with 'as! String'. Succeeds with 'as! NSString'.
        let pathString = paths[0]

        // This line always fails with the error. I can't interact with pathString without it failing.
        // Including something as simple as asking for its length.
        let filePath = pathString.stringByAppendingPathComponent("download.pdf")
    }
}
```

Oddly the debugger seems to show the `paths` array as empty (not nil though), yet if it gets past that line `pathString` is correctly set.

This is happening in iOS 7.1, simulator and device. I haven't had a chance to test it in iOS 8. Xcode 6.3, Swift 1.2

Comment: `as! [String]` works without problems for me.

Comment: @MartinR yeah, doesn't work for me though - please see this screenshot: https://gyazo.com/e6e6d1d90743fd7b6c7382652244b31a

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but the last line is better written as `let filePath = pathString.stringByAppendingPathComponent("download.pdf")`.

Comment: I filled out the code a little to give context

Comment: `as [NSString]` works for me

Comment: @DhavalThanki yeah, as [NSString] works for me too until I try and interact with pathString. That throws the error.

Comment: can you write the `error`?

Comment: @DhavalThanki Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1 address=0x20)